# Save python df to Digital Ocean Database

Tags: python, database, digital-ocean

I am trying to set my python script to automatically run and save the data to a database on Digital Ocean droplets.

So I created the data df.  I want it to append to the database each time it runs.  This is my first time using it so I might have misunderstood what is possible.

```
conn_params = {
        "host": "_",
        "database": "_",
        "user": "_",
        "password": "_",
        "port": "_"
}

conn = psycopg2.connect(**conn_params)

df.to_sql("mydata", conn, if_exists="append", index=False)
conn.close()
```

This is what I have but it's not right.  I filled in the appropriate parameters with the ones on my Digital Ocean database website.

Comment: [`pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas-dataframe-to-sql) expects either `sqlalchemy.engine.(Engine or Connection)` or `sqlite3.Connection`, not psycopg connection

Comment: Thank you. I have changed it.  Now the problem is a lack of primary key, but I suppose that's for a different thread.
`connection_string='mysql+pymysql://username:password@hostname:port/database_name'
engine = create_engine(connection_string)`